# Spring repository+hibernate after save entity not create ID

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, entity, spring-data-jpa

I have entity:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

I create table in postgresql with flyway:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id                     BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
```

And When I tried save entity - it saved but without ID.

I tried change IDENTITY to AUTO - but then I get error `hibernate could not find sequence hibernate_sequence` and `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate"` not work.

How can I need configure hibernate and entity for save?

Comment: Define "saved but without ID"? The whole point of "IDENTITY" strategy and "BIGSERIAL"/"SERIAL" type is that they are auto-incremented so not part of the INSERT statement.

Comment: Order savedOrder = orderRepository.save(order); - work fine
then after save savedOrder.getId() == NULL and in Order table not saved row

Comment: so look in the log of your chosen JPA provider ...